# Use files in a folder - exceptions VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, directory, do-while

I need to perform a certain task over some excel files located in subfolders (which are inside a folder). This task must exclude all those file's names that contain the letter `"v"`.

I used file name length since the files I want to use have that length (file names with letter "V" have more than 28 characters). Here is my code.

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Fso As Object, objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim FileInFolder As Object

FromPath = "C:\Prueba"
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFolder = Fso.GetFolder(FromPath)

For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.Subfolders

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String, File As Variant
    Path = objSubFolder.Path
    Filename = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx")

    For Each File In objSubFolder.Files
        If Len(Filename) = 28 Then 
            Do something
            wbk.Close True
            Filename = Dir
        End If
     Next File
Next objSubFolder

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code works OK until it reaches a file with "V". It just stuck in that file (do nothing, which is good) and then goes to the next subfolder, ignoring all the remaining excel files.

I need some advice on how to deal with this.

thx

Comment: maybe it has to do with this part of the code: `Do something
            wbk.Close True`. What is `wbk` used for?

Comment: @AAA I used wbk inside the Do something section [Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & Filename)]. Basically, It allows me to open the excel file and work with it.

Comment: add an else statement so that you can see what's happening when > 28 and include a `Stop` and see what is open or what is happening. You may need to close the file, or something.

Comment: @PGCodeRider I already did it. The problem comes from line Filename = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx"). It doesn't change (stuck with the same "V" file)

Comment: I think I got it. I find the action Filename = Dir must end for that case too. Txs